# can i get data from the object from observeValueForKeyPath iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, key-value-observing

I want to get a number of variables from the target of the function

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

but XCode wont compile if I say `object.somevalue` - I am using `[change objectForKey:@"new"]` to get the changed value, but I want to get more values and I dont want to break the MVC I've got setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know what Class `object` is, it only know where to find it (through the id pointer). It won't let you compile code that accesses `somevalue` because it doesn't know where to go looking for it. Thus, you either have to cast the object to what you know it is, or send it a message using the bracket notation: `[object somevalue]` and live with the warning it gives.